# Formulario de Contacto sin PHP

Tags: firebase

He trasladado mi página web a Firebase, pues todo es estático a excepción del formlario de contacto que requiere de PHP, cosa que no permite firebase.

¿Hay alguna forma de construir un formulario de contacto que no requiera de PHP para funcionar?
Encontré opciones como [Fromspree](https://formspree.io/) o [Getform](https://getform.io/) Sin emabrgo no quiero que salga el Branding de dichas webs pues pagar por un plan premium para mi web que siendo honestos alguien rara vez usará mi formulario.

Tengo cuenta en MailGun, hay alguna forma de hacer lo que hace formspree o Getform con mailgun?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: No necesitas templates de formularios para poder usar la base de datos de Firebase. Con Firebase se puede construir formularios totalmente personalizados y luego guardar los datos por medio de JavaScript, por ejemplo. De esa forma podrías evitar usar PHP. Te recomiendo que leas la [documentación oficial de Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup)  para aprender a hacerlo.